# No process with the specified Id is running ( VS code )

Tags: visual-studio-code, razor, vscode-debugger, .net-8.0

I'm facing an issue while attempting to debug my .NET 8 application using Visual Studio Code. I have configured the debug settings in the launch.json file, but each time I press F5, I encounter the following error. I am unsure how to successfully debug my application and properly attach it to the dotnet process.

```
{
// Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
// Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
// For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    
    {
        "name": ".NET Core Attach",
        "type": "coreclr",
        "request": "attach",
        "processId": "${command:pickProcess}"
    }

 ]
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

- Open VS Code
- Open the project
- Make sure the extensions are installed [C#](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-dotnettools.csharp), [C# Dev Kit](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-dotnettools.csdevkit), [C# IntelliCode](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-dotnettools.vscodeintellicode-csharp) this is optional
- `ctrl + p` and type `NET: GENERATE ASSETS FOR BUILD AND DEBUG`
- now the assests will be generated now build the project.

Comment: I've tried this , I got this `error : Command '.NET: Generate Assets for Build and Debug' resulted in an error.`